# Can I update the Version of El Capitan from the Apple Store, if I bought it from a 3rd Party?

Tags: macos, apple-store

I don't want to buy High Sierra, because some of my applications software won't work, if I do.  So I bought a copy of 10.11 from a 3rd Party.

Can I get updates (10.11.2, 10.11.3, etc) from the Apple Store, since I did not buy the operating system from them?

Answer (score 2):

1. you shouldn't have 'bought' 10.10 or 10.11 from ANYBODY, because it's free.
2. you'll need to create/have an Apple ID to do updates...
3. as long as your installation of 10.11 isn't corrupted or a hack (which I'd suspect is possible, as you allegedly paid money for it), you should be able to pull down all updates from Apple..